# Android logo as an emoji (symbol) to copy and paste in text form

Tags: android, text, emoji

I'm looking for an Android logo emoji (symbol, not a picture), so that I can use it in text editors.
A website with different emoji is for example https://emojipedia.org/
Unfortunately I couldn't find the Android logo there.
I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks a lot and best regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also searching the same thing but couldn't find it, same like apple logo  I can't find for android

Answer (score 2):

I could not find either. An alternative I used is ascii of play symbol -> ▶

Answer (score -1):

If your use case is HTML, Then you can get it from  https://fontawesome.com/ , they got tons of icons and with official licensing too. Go check it out.

Comment: I need the Android logo as a symbol like this here: ✏️